# Generic algorithm for the rotation of vectors around an axis without using matrixes or quaternions?

Tags: math, vector, rotation, formula

I don't understand why matrixes and quaternions are necessary for that operation. Why don't we just write a function such as `rotate(vector,axis,angle)` which applies an algebraic formula, performing the rotation directly? What would be that formula?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to have a matrix object (it just makes it a lot easier) to do that.
You can of course have the algebraic formula to do that and the formula is the formula for matrix multiplication with a vector.
But again - the matrix notion is just a way to remember the formula, nothing else.

Quaternion multiplication is just a different way to remember (express) the same formula. 
But again again - it's the same formula written in a different (very clever indeed) way.

You can't have two different formulas to do the same thing, right - any two should be equivalent to each other.

Comment: So you mean in the end the algebraic formulas are the same for both cases? Might I ask to see those algebraic equations? Are them big?

Comment: You can see the formulas by figuring out what the matrix is and then performing the multiplication by hand and take the result - it's a lot longer expression than the matrix one of course.
And just to be mathematically correct - at the end the formulas are not literally the same, but they are equivalent, i.e. you can derive one from the other and vice verse.

Answer (score 1):

Because the 'algebraic formula' will be functionally equivalent. Could you easily discern useful properties like concatenations and inverses without these more abstract concepts?

And abstraction is one of the fundamentals of programming.